# distinguishing between a string and an int in scanf when there is no space

Tags: c, string, int, scanf

I'm trying to distinguish a string from an int and separate the two using scanf().

for example: Ron Burgundy41

Is it possible to use `scanf("%s %s %i", name, last_name, &number)`

and get

name = Ron

last_name = Burgundy

number = 41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , it is very possible . You can write your `scanf` like this -

```
if(scanf("%19s %19[^0-9]%d",name,last_name,&number)==3){   //assuming both array of size 20
/*                  ^ this will read and store in array until a numbers is encountered */
   // print them 
}
```

[Click on link to see working code](https://ideone.com/ZoQqRa)